# Получить название города по IP

Tags: jquery, геолокация

Сейчас делаю так:

```
jQuery.getJSON("http://freegeoip.net/json/", function(data) {
    var city = data.city;

    var lat = data.latitude;
    var lng = data.longitude;

    jQuery('#curr_location').html(city);
});
```

Сейчас как описано выше. Но город получаю в латинице. Есть способ или другой API для получения города в кириллице?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Этот сервис, как следует из описания, использует [базы maxmind.com](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/). У них есть разбивка по языкам, но какуй именно язык выбирать вы указать не можете. Варианты:

1. [Подключаться к maxmind.com самостоятельно](http://dev.maxmind.com/#GeoIP2) (а можно скачивать базы с нужной локализацией к себе на сервер и работать с ними напрямую)
2. Использовать [SypexGeo](http://sypexgeo.net/ru/docs/) (там тоже есть и API, и возможность работать с локальными базами)
3. Выбрать какой-нибудь другой сервис :-)

Answer (score 3):

Вот ру сервис 
http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip=88.200.175.133

```
<ip-answer>
<ip value="88.200.175.133">
<inetnum>88.200.172.0 - 88.200.175.255</inetnum>
<country>RU</country>
<city>Тольятти</city>
<region>Самарская область</region>
<district>Приволжский федеральный округ</district>
<lat>53.535561</lat>
<lng>49.409569</lng>
</ip>
</ip-answer>
```